# Checking equality of indices of multiple pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check whether the indices of a bunch of Pandas dataframes are the same. I have written the following function which takes in a tuple of dataframes as input.

```
def chk_index_match(*dfs):
    ran_once = False
    for df in dfs:
        if not ran_once:
            ref_df = df
            ran_once = True
        else:
            if not(ref_df.index.equals(df.index)):
                return False
    return True
```

Is there a builtin Pandas function that does something similar? Or a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way I found, not sure if it is better as such but it uses more ready-made functions and fewer lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
def chk_index_match(*dfs):
    arrays = [np.array(df.index) for df in dfs]
    return np.all([np.array_equal(arrays[0], a) for a in arrays])
```